# Docker - COPY/ADD files remove the trailing line

Tags: docker, line, yaml, trailing

It is really strange what is happening. I check several time. I have a docker image copying/adding a yml file to the container. This yml file has trailing line. I added three empty line to be sure.

If I go to the container and do a cat those trailing line are not here any more. Which cause the following error:

```
YAML Error: Stream does not end with newline character
YAML_PARSE_ERR_NO_FINAL_NEWLINE
```

Comment: This doesn't occur on `Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5` when using COPY on a directory

Comment: Yeah somehow I cannot reproduce :(

Comment: This *does* occur in Docker 18.06.1-ce-mac73 (26764) with Compose: 1.22.0.